"Toggle" custom style in MS Word with shortcut
In MS Word I'd like to have a custom "style" with a specific color and font, that I can toggle on and off ideally with a shortcut. I want to use it to highlight excel formulas in my case. Is there a way to achieve this? In fact the mechanism of "styles" doesn't seem to be appropriate, I'd like it to behave more like bold or italic which I can toggle with ctrl+b and ctrl+i ...

You can create a custom Character Style and attach a keyboard shortcut for it.
You can turn it off with the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Spacebar. That shortcut returns the text to the formatting of the underlying paragraph style (also known as the default paragraph font).
Here is a link to my article on the Microsoft site on Assigning Keyboard Shortcuts.
To use the same keyboard shortcut to toggle would require writing a macro.

Ahh great, the ctrl+spacebar shortcut is exactly what i was looking for! the only problem is that it collides with the quick launcher in powertoys, and I can't figure out how to change it ...

That would likely be in PowerToys settings. Otherwise, you can add a different shortcut in Word. The command, found under All Commands, is ResetChar. See my article on shortcuts at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330.

I think it's called ResetChar in English, but I can't find the command in French ...

Turn off PowerToys. Then, in Word, go to the Assign Keyboard Shortcut dialog and put your insertion point in the box for creating a shortcut. Press Ctrl+Spacebar and see what command that is currently assigned to in French. Find that command and assign your new shortcut.  -- Alternatively, ask yourself whether you need PowerToys active by default.

Thanks! I found the name in french, it's RétablirCar
